# Unable to install angular CLI in windows 10

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

Unable to install Angular CLI with npm on windows 10

I have tried all the solutions

1. Tried clearing the cache and re-running, every time I try to install - npm install -g @angular/cli - every time new error comes starting with "Unexpected end of JSON"
2. Tried uninstalling and installing again node js
3. Tried as Admin and non admin
4. Tried in CMD and Powershell
5. Restarted machine
6. Still not able to install angular/cli after 12 hours

Looks like node is full buggy system

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or using a proxy? Sometimes companies redirect to their own npm repository and don't keep it up to date. There were some suggestions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8572 The one by `nevernet` may work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,It will help you.

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Removes npm cache forcefully if you get warning using npm cache clean.

Then try

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

I have successfully installed by trying the above solution in Windows10.